# How to set up an Sun SPARC T5120 from scratch?

Tags: sun, sparc

Hello I am a newbie when it comes to server set up, especially SUN SPARC server since I never worked with this architecture.

At work I have an Sun SPARC T5120 server that is not used anymore, I want to set it up as a completely new server. I don´t care for what are the current files in it and configurations.

I read the "Getting Started Guide"oracle documentation which says to connect a serial cable between the server’s SER MGT port and a terminal device, but since this is not a new server, this doesn´t work, as it is not the first time to system is booted.

Can anyone help me how to access this server and reconfigure it ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any information of IP addresses used by its Service Processor? You may get into it over the network. The serial port should work also, despite the network being already configured.

Comment: No I don´t know the IP address used by the SP. The server was powered off in a rack for so long everyone forgo about it. I tried to connect to the serial port using the configuration described in the docs (9600 baud, 8 bit, no parity, 1 stop bit) but nothing so far...

Comment: Do you see any output on the serial port while rebooting the server? I mean a complete power off, including removing both power cables. If the cable is correct, you should at least see some gibberish if your speed does not match the one configured at the port. Then, I would certainly try all higher speeds, starting at @115200 N81, then 19200, 38400, 57600, etc.

Comment: Oh, do not forget to check the [RTC battery](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19839-01/E21875-01/z40002fb1407850.html). Change it,  Older Sun models are known to "appear dead" if the battery is so bad it presents an uncharacteristic resistance.

Comment: Just don't - it's an 8 year old server!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Blockquote oracle documentation which says to connect a serial cable between the server’s SER MGT port and a terminal device
>   Blockquote

As it says, doesn't have to be first boot. Connect with Putty or some such console software from another machine using a Cisco cable. Default settings are 9600, 8, none, 1, no flow control.
That'll get you to a login prompt, this is the service processor. Default login/pass is root/changeme.

That's about as far as I've made it, drives are wiped so I'm still working on what OS to use and where to get it from. I have a T5240, so they're similar.

Good luck!